# How to get datetime from google calendar

Tags: java, datetime

```
EventDateTime d1 = event.getStart();
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
String outputDate = outputFormat.format(d1.getDate());
```

I'm unable to get the date in String.

Answer (score 1):

`EventDateFormat.getDate()` gets
`The date, in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", if this is an all-day event.`

You probably want to use [getDateTime()](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg-history/71c8e9b19946f57835aaceee8ed2561c7f76a6f6/apis/calendar/v3/com/google/api/services/calendar/model/EventDateTime.html#getDateTime%28%29) instead.